# Is there a way to not trigger Gmail smart reply from the content of the email?

Tags: gmail

I've seen a lot of questions about disabling the Gmail smart reply feature from the *user* point of view, but nothing about it from a *server/app* PoV.

In our application, we send some emails containing data about future events or inquiring schedule availability, each email including a link to a dedicated page of our app to answer.

But Gmail doesn't understand it's an automated email, even if the sender is a `no-reply@my.app.com` address, and keeps suggesting "smart" replies. This provides a terrible UX, where the email ends with a fine answer button, then Gmail suggested replies which leads to an unused address.

Does someone knows if there is a way to force it to suggest nothing? The only solution we've got so far is to change the content of the message, trying to find specific words that won't trigger Gmail feature :-/

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Xavier?

Comment: Forgot to answer my own question but yes, kind of. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to hide the GMail smart replies by adding a footer note in our emails, stating that this is an automated message and that user should not reply to it. Seems to do the trick for now :)

In french, this looks like:

> Cet email est un envoi automatique ; merci de ne pas y répondre.

Comment: Thanks for adding that Xavier, the language of the email does seem to have a big impact as most newsletters I get don't trigger Smart Reply. For us though the email we send does allow human replies, it's not a fully automated but we prefer if people use the action button than reply. We will keep tinkering till there is a standard method.